# Can not insert UTF8 to Database MySQL in Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, utf-8

When create table, I have setted charset = utf8.

I create 1 store procedure to insert data to database.

1. When insert data UTF8 to Database on Window, it works OK.(Display data correctly)
2. But it doesnot work in Linux.(Display data not correctly)

The strange thing is insert UTF8 **work fine in window**, but when i **deploy MySQL in linux, when insert data to database it insert wrong UTF8** value.

Thanks for help

Edit: Update more detail follow comment of @Col. Shrapnel

Comment: Sorry, my mean is data display not correctly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should start mysql console with --default-character-set=utf8:

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -uyour_user -p
```

Comment: Thanks.  You saved my hours.

Not exactly a linux problem in my case.  I was running an sql script which contained UTF-8 data in INSERT statements.  I was using mysql.exe on the command line.  

mysql.exe -uname -ppassword < script.sql

Comment: Thanks, it helps me on Windows as well to install the unicode data via batch script.

Answer (score 3):

most probably you didn't specify client character set by issuing `SET NAMES UTF8` query

but there can be other problems - your database or a web page may be not in the utf-8

Comment: I try to insert into Database with original SQLcommand. For example:

insert into tbData values('UTF8-Data','');

It does NOT insert correct UTF8 value to database. 
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: @nguyendat you must execute `SET NAMES UTF8` query **before** any other query. just make it below connect statement

Answer (score 3):

I just found a solution for my problem: Edit file my.cnf under /etc/my.cnf as below:

```
[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

But i still confuse why this bug occur in Linux, not in Window.

Comment: This is not a bug, this is a configuration issue.